# How to solve ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b in Lean

Tags: boolean, lean

I tried solving this but could not, any help? My solution so far:

```
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=
begin
     assume a b,
     cases a:b,
     cases b,
     cases a,
     have c : tt ≠ ff,
     contradiction,
     sorry,
end
```

Comment: Now consider a function f on, say, weekdays, and prove f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f d))))))) = f d. And after that, the general case: let T be an enumeration with k values, and f: T→T, then forall  x:T applying f k times to (f x) = (f x)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unusual question for me (I'm a mathematician so `bool` doesn't exist for me), so I may be missing the efficient way to do it, but you can certainly case bash on all possibilities for `a tt`, `a ff` and `b`.

```
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=
begin
     assume a b,
     cases h₁ : a tt ; 
     cases h₂ : a ff ;  
     cases b,
     repeat { rw h₁ <|> rw h₂ },
end
```

(slightly simplified in edit)

Don't hesitate to ask if part of the syntax is unclear (or better, come and ask on [Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/)).

I'm not really sure what you were doing in your attempt. But your line `cases a:b` creates a new thing called `a` in your context, which is very likely to cause confusion. And the fact that the `contradiction` tactic succeeds is an unfortunate accident, it would be clearer to use `trivial` here.

Answer (score 0):

Using your tactic style:

```
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=
begin
  assume a b,
  -- split reasoning into b as ff or tt
  cases hb : b,
  { -- in this case, all b is now ff
    -- so let's split what (a ff) is into ff and tt
    -- since we have two (a ff) expressions in our goal
    cases hf : a ff,
    { -- this case is where (a ff) = ff,
      -- so we use it directly twice
      exact hf.symm ▸ hf },
    { -- in this case, (a ff) = tt, so now we have
      -- the expression (a tt) in our goal
      -- we split it into the cases ff and tt
      cases ht : a tt,
      { -- in this case, we already have the goal, use it
        exact hf },
      { -- in this case, we already have the goal, use it
        exact ht } } },
  { -- in this case, all b is now ff
    -- so let's split what (a tt) is into ff and tt
    -- since we have two (a tt) expressions in our goal
    cases ht : a tt,
    { -- in this case, (a tt) = ff, so now we have
      -- the expression (a ff) in our goal
      -- we split it into the cases ff and tt
      cases hf : a ff,
      { -- in this case, we already have the goal, use it
        exact hf },
      { -- in this case, we already have the goal, use it
         exact ht } },
    { -- this case is where (a tt) = tt,
      -- so we use it directly twice
      exact ht.symm ▸ ht } },
end
```

and in a case-bash variant, still without tactics:

```
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=
begin
  intros a b,
  -- split reasoning into b as ff or tt
  cases hb : b;
  -- and for all cases, split reasoning of the (a ff) expression
  cases hf : a ff;
  -- and for all cases, split reasoning of the (a tt) expression
  cases ht : a tt,
  -- now deal with all cases
  { exact hf.symm ▸ hf },
  { exact hf.symm ▸ hf },
  { exact hf },
  { exact ht },
  { exact hf.symm ▸ hf },
  { exact ht.symm ▸ ht },
  { exact hf.symm ▸ ht },
  { exact ht.symm ▸ ht },
end
```

and finally, using simple tactics:

```
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=
begin
  intros a b,
  -- split reasoning into b as ff or tt
  cases hb : b;
  -- and for all cases, split reasoning of the (a ff) expression
  cases hf : a ff;
  -- and for all cases, split reasoning of the (a tt) expression
  cases ht : a tt;
  -- now deal with all cases using tactics
  all_goals {
    -- we can try rewriting either (a ff) or (a tt) which must occur
    -- in the goal expression because of the original (a b) expression
    -- and only one of those is present, so we use the
    -- <|> syntax to try the second tactic (rw) if the first one fails
    rw ht <|> rw hf,
    -- now, either we've formed a reflexive equality and we're done
    -- or the equality we're left with is of the form (a tt = ff)
    -- which we'll have as an assumption
    -- if tactic we tried to use here was a plain "assumption",
    -- that would fail in the cases where we had already solved the goal
    -- so we wrap it in a "try"
    try { assumption } },
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you help, I am new to lean so I was just wondering what does "exact hf.symm ▸ hf" mean/do?? Is it shorthand for exact hf, symmetry??

Comment: Are you familiar with the `rewrite` tactic?

Comment: In this case specifically, we have that `hf` stands for `a ff = ff`. And we're trying to show that `a (a ff) = ff`. So we need to replace the  `a ff` inside with `ff`. Luckily, `hf` states exactly that. So we provide the statement `ff = a ff` to the `_ ▸ hf`, which means, use the expression "y = x" on the left of the arrow to replace all occurrences of x with y. So to replace `a ff` with `ff`, we need to have `ff = a ff` to the left of the arrow, which is `hf.symm`.

Comment: Yes, I think it rearranges the assumption to match the goal

Comment: In this particular case, saying `exact hf.symm ▸ hf` is basically the same as `rw hf, exact hf`. Or if it was `exact hf.symm ▸ ht`, then `rw hf, exact ht`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheating solution:

```
import tactic.fin_cases                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                        
example : ∀ a : bool → bool, ∀ b : bool, a (a (a b)) = a b :=                                                                           
begin                                                                                                                                   
  intros a b,                                                                                                                           
  fin_cases a; fin_cases b; refl                                                                                                        
end
```

Here `fin_cases` is a tactic from `mathlib`. It does cases analysis on `a : α` if it can find a computable `[fintype α]`. So, mathematically the solution says: consider all cases, verify that in each case we have a definitional equality.